# Using and Abusing wikipedia/investopedia as a source. Is it an issue?

Tags: discussion

Im interested in improving my answering methods for this site.

For the most part I'm sourcing most of my answers either from Wikipedia or Investopedia, sometimes even just copying and pasting and would really like to know if original answers are necessary for this site and want to know how I can improve the quality of my answers (ie. a format or set of instructions).

Comment: If you happen to have access to the [Palgrave Dictionary of Economics](http://www.dictionaryofeconomics.com/dictionary), that is a much better source of articles than Wikipedia. Also, I would use journal articles or working papers as much as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues here, regarding answers:

**1) Correctness**
Wikipedia and Investopedia have, in general, a positive record as regards the correctness of what their Economics and Econometrics lemmas include (although incomplete in many cases), but it would be advisable to use them as sources only if you can feel certain that the lemma you are sourcing from is indeed correct. This leads to the following general suggestion:

> We should not answer questions just because we can find an answer in an
>   online encyclopedia - we should answer questions we already know something
>   about.

**2) Originality**
In a site such as ours that asks for answers based on mathematics, data and relevant scientific literature, "originality" has to do mainly with *how* the answerer will combine knowledge and sources to provide help for the OP and long-lasting high-quality content for the site. Then "copy-pasting" sources (irrespective of whether one acknowledges the act or not), is not very "original", except when we do feel that the exact passage summarizes very well the issues, or when what we want is to *relay* information about, say, the contents of a book.

Still, in such cases my suggestion would be to **explicitly** quote *and* come up with a commentary after the quote, even if it is only something like "I don't think I can summarize the issue better than the above quote", or "from how the author discusses the contents of his book, we see that he focuses mainly on..., leaving perhaps less space for...". This creates *originality* in the answer, a characteristic that is seen to be different from *original material* strictly defined.

**Caveat:** I may have not always "follow my own advice" in every single answer I have posted on this site as regards "copy-pasting" from sources. But my suggestions stand, and I better make sure that I will follow them in the future.

Comment: +1 I would just add that, if we answer a question we already know something about from a textbook or academic paper, a supporting reference from Wikipedia or Investopedia, which are readily accessible to all, is sometimes more helpful than one to the textbook or paper.  People may not have that textbook (or that edition of it) to hand, and for some the paper may be behind a paywall.

Comment: @AdamBailey  Thank you, this is a very good and helpful point you are making.